# Evaluation metrics not displayed on Tensorboard

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

When training a Tensorflow object detection model, I want to view the mean average precision (mAP) of my test data. Running train.py and eval.py in two consoles, I can view the loss rates of the training data, and even the objects detected in the test set images through

tensorboard --logdir=model_dir/

however no precision scalars are being displayed for the test set.

I am using python 3 on windows 10, and successfully installed pycocotools using;

pip install git+https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi.git#subdirectory=PythonAPI

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I had this problem, hence the upvote. But I simply wasnt waiting long enough. Leave the eval running for the at least couple of hours or longer alongside the train job.

Answer (score 0):

@Graham Monkman is it a must for the eval and train job to run together so that I can get the evaluation metrics (mAP, etc..) ?

Comment: It is a must - if you want to see the evaluation on the validation set. Locally I found this to be slow to run simultaneously, as such it took a while to appear on tensorboard.